# How to use automapper with convertusing and a condition?

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

We are using automapper in .net core to map viewmodels to dtos. For datetime we would like to save utc to our database, but for the user we would like to display local timezone.
This goes well with a ConvertUsing like this:

```
CreateMap<CreateAgendaItemViewModel, AgendaItemDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.StartDateTime, opt => opt.ConvertUsing(new ToUtcTimeConverter()))
.ReverseMap()
.ForMember(dest => dest.StartDateTime, opt => opt.ConvertUsing(new ToLocalTimeConverter()))
```

So far so good if you always want to change the time. However it is possible that only a date is set and not a time (because it is an all day event) and we would like to keep the time as is like this: 2020-04-09 00:00:00.0000000. We have a boolean in the models that indicates if it is indeed an all day event or not. How can we condition the convertusing?

We already tried MapFrom with condition, but it cannot have a convertusing. We also tried this, but it ended up not being mapped, or being mapped to utc time.

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.StartDateTime, opt => { opt.Condition(src => !src.AllDayEvent); opt.ConvertUsing(new ToUtcTimeConverter()); })
```

Comment: Try a `PreCondition`. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu How can a PreCondition solve this problem? She wants to use a ValueConverter only when a condition is met, otherwise use the default mapping. I don't know if this is possible in AutoMapper.

Comment: A `PreCondition` will allow you to skip the converter altogether. If that's not the point, you control what gets assigned, so just do that.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Ok, but is a property is skipped by the PreCondition, it will not get mapped at all. That's the problem, it should be mapped with the Custom ValueConverter only if another property of the source object is true. Otherwise it should use the default conversion but not skip the property. I cannot find a way in the Automapper documentation to do just that.

Comment: You need a value resolver here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the possible solutions in the comments. I tried the custom valueconvert, however I ended up with a lot of classes for each type of convert, while we have multiple sources and destinations that request the same solution. That is not what I wanted.
But I also found out that convertUsing with a condition was not the way to go for this problem.
This is how I solved the check and the mapping:

```
 CreateMap<AgendaItemViewModel, AgendaItemDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.StartDateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AllDayEvent ? src.StartDateTime : src.StartDateTime.ToUniversalTime()))
.ReverseMap()
.ForMember(dest => dest.StartDateTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AllDayEvent ? src.StartDateTime : src.StartDateTime.ToLocalTimeZoneTime()))
```

So ToUniversalTimeZone is DateTime extension and I created our own ToLocalTimeZoneTime extension.